# C# CheckBoxList update in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

Please inspect my C# code below and let me know where I am going wrong. Here is what I am experiencing:

1.) If I empty the `SendReport` column in SQL Server and load the page, the second row of the `SendReport` automatically gets populated with a 1.

2.) I can place a checkmark, click the button and the `SendReport` values successfully populate in SQL Server. However, if I uncheck any of them and click the button, none of the values change from 1 to 0. Please help!

```
$<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />


BACKPAGE:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindCheckBoxList();
    }
}

//  Setting up the ConnectionString
public string GetConnectionString()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPdataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}

//  Binding the CheckBoxList with Data
private void BindCheckBoxList()
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
  try
  {
    connection.Open();
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT Partner, ID, SendReport FROM Rorts";
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
      CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dt;
      CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Partner"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
      CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "SendReport"; // the id of the items displayed
      CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

      //Setting the Selected Items in the ChecBoxList based from the value in the database
      //to do this, lets iterate to each items in the list
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i]["SendReport"].ToString()))
        {
          CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["SendReport"]);
        }
      }
    }

  }
  catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
  {
    string msg = "Fetch Error:";
    msg += ex.Message;
    throw new Exception(msg);
  }
  finally
  {
    connection.Close();
  }
}

//  Creating the Method for Saving the CheckBoxList Selected Items to the database
private void Update(string name, bool SendReport)
{
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
  SqlCommand cmd;
  string sqlStatement = string.Empty;
    try
    {
      // open the Sql connection
      connection.Open();
      sqlStatement = "UPDATE Rorts SET SendReport = @SendReport WHERE Partner = @Partner";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Partner", name);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SendReport", SendReport);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
      string msg = "Insert/Update Error:";
      msg += ex.Message;
      throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
      // close the Sql Connection
      connection.Close();
    }
  }

//  Calling the Method for Saving the state of  CheckBoxList  selected items
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PartnerName = string.Empty;

  for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        PartnerName = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text;
        Update(PartnerName, CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected);
    }
  }
  //ReBind the List to retain the selected items on postbacks
  BindCheckBoxList();
}
```

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you should accept answers to your questions...

Comment: I have asked multiple times how to do it and noone will tell me.

Comment: Check the checkbox below the correct answer.  See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Thanks! I have reviewed my questions/answers and updated them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is due to the if block below from the Button1 click event handler.  The result is that only the check boxes that are checked have the values persisted to the database.

```
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            PartnerName = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text;
            Update(PartnerName, CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected);
        }
```

You can just remove the if statement and persist all of the values or add logic to only persist those that have changed.